# American coming to Scotland from overstay in Spain

Tags: uk, us-citizens, spain, overstaying, visa-free-entry

I’ve overstayed in Spain by 9 months but fell in love and now going to Scotland so my girlfriend can get a US visa. How difficult will it be to get into Scotland? Please help

Comment: How will going to Scotland help your girlfriend acquire a US visa? You’re confused.You dont need a visa to enter Scotland if you’re a US citizen.

Comment: The OP has to leave Spain before he can get into Scotland. After a nine month overstay he will attract a fine, probably an entry ban, and risks being deported directly to the USA. It's also possible that his immigration status will be shared with the UK, making entry to Scotland difficult if not impossible.

Comment: We have a flight in two days. I’m aware we don’t need to go to Scotland to get the visa however it’s the most affordable option. If I’m able to leave Spain without being noticed as an overstayer how likely is it that I’ll be able to enter Scotland without issue?

Comment: @Davidmiller Your chances of leaving without being spotted are small. Your chances of being allowed entry to Scotland depend on many things. We couldn't give you an assessment.

Comment: @CannonFodder "risks being deported directly to the USA": really?  Of course that is theoretically possible, but does it ever actually happen? Why would any country spend time, money, or other resources to deport someone who is already literally on the way out?  Being sent to the US by the UK, on the other hand, is a very real possibility.

Comment: @phoog I've no idea, but i've seen it listed as a possible sanction elsewhere, hence 'risks'

Comment: Please indicate if you are a US national, or a national of some other country, and your legal status in Spain (which visa or regulation you used to come to Spain).

Comment: @David miller If that’s your real name, probably best not to publicise it on TSE. At the border you should be prepared to answer questions on the purpose and length of your stay and means of support, if asked

Comment: "I’m aware we don’t need to go to Scotland to get the visa however it’s the most affordable option": US visa fees are the same everywhere.  What kind of visa is she going to apply for, and what is her nationality?

Answer (score 5):

Nobody can tell you how difficult it will be for you to get into Scotland.  You will either be admitted to the UK or sent to the US.  The probability of either outcome depends on factors that we do not know, some of which we cannot know, such as the mood of the immigration officer who interviews you on arrival in the UK and on your ability to present a coherent explanation of your circumstances.

It makes far more sense for your girlfriend to apply for her visa in Spain and for you to travel directly from Spain to the US.

Comment: OP could get flagged up as they will have to go through exit immigration as they are leaving the Schengen area and not even make it to the UK

Comment: @BritishSam I just find it unlikely that Spain would detain and deport someone whom they discover at exit immigration.  It seems a waste of time and money.  I have never heard of anything like that happening; have you?

Comment: true probably a fine if anything, plus Spain have some of the most lax exit controls I've seen, my partner has a non EU passport, sometimes they just glance at it and she has to ask for it to have an exit stamp.